# Como definir a opacidade de um elemento de dentro de uma div maior que o da própria div

Tags: css

Como pode-se ver, a opacidade do `button` está maior que a da `div`, mas mesmo assim ele está na mesma opacidade, como eu poderia mudar isso ??

```css
.div1
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #6a6a6a;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.button
{ 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <input type="image" class="button" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/users-group_318-48680.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: .button
{ 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

Note que, a opacity está marcada como 1.0, isto equivale a sua opacidade normal (100%), para poder usar um uma opacidade menor, atribua (0.1 até 0.9)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer usando `position absolute` e posicionando um em cima do outro.

```
.div1
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #6a6a6a;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
.button
{ 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top:25px;
  left:25px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
```

Dependendo da cor do background você pode alterar a própria cor do elemento principal e definir uma opacidade para ela:

```
div1{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde.
Notei que o button está com o valor original da imagem definido em opacidade, o que não implicará em qualquer mudança, teste este código e veja se os problemas foram sanados.

```css
.div1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #6a6a6a;
  opacity: 0.5; /*Neste caso, utilize de 0.1 até 0.9 para definir uma opacidade, e 1.0 para seu valor original.*/
}
      
.button{ 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
 opacity: 0.5;

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Teste</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="div1">
  <input type="image" class="button" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/users-group_318-48680.jpg">
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

O que esta acontecendo é o seguinte, seu elemento `div1` esta com opacidade `0.5` ou seja tudo que estiver dentro dele vai fica com opacidade, se você quer um background transparente a melhor opção é usar cores no formato `rgba` segue exemplo:

```css
.div1
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.5);
}
.button
{ 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <input type="image" class="button" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/users-group_318-48680.jpg">
</div>
```

Observe que converti sua cor de hexadecimal para rgba.

Comment: Sim, porem algumas cores acredito que não fiquem igual, como por exemplo, essa `#69e673`;

Comment: @LucasCarezia como assim? tudo depende de quanto vc quer de transparência um bg black com opacidade 0.5 equivale a `rgba(0,0,0,.5)`